# Ui-Select usage in UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs

After getting a successful response to my first question in this forum, I am delighted to present another.  I have used Brian Hamm's mehodology to use a ui-select in ui-grid. Maybe I did not implement properly, but I have this question: how can one get the cell to display the selected value from the dropdown list as opposed to the value that is entered in the database.  Eg

column for gridoptions:

```
{ field: 'projectorebody_id', 
            name: 'projectorebody_id', 
            displayName: 'Select',
            cellTemplate: '../app/views/projects/eporebodiesdropdown.html',
            editDropdownOptionsArray: vm.orebodies,
            width: '10%' },
```

The celltemplate:

```
<ui-select-wrap>
<ui-select ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" theme="selectize"
    append-to-body="true">

  <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose...">{{ COL_FIELD }}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item.projectorebody_id as item in col.colDef.editDropdownOptionsArray | filter: $select.search">
    <span>{{ item.orebodyName }}</span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
</ui-select-wrap>
```

ui-select-wrap is a directive written by Brian Hamm which has the effect that the dropdown does not remain open when one moves away from the column.

At present, the ui-select occupies the entire cell. It displays item.projectorebody_id.  See image below..Select is the column with the dropdown. You can see it displays the id (item.projectorebody_id). The next column, Orebody, displays the orebodyName (ie the descriptive value from the dropdown..if the dropdown were to display this value, then I would need this column.

[Image of cell with column selected being the ui-select dropdown..you can see it displaying the id of the underlying field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TMti.jpg)

Now an image of the dropdown when selected:

[Dropdown when selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU5hX.jpg)

When clicked, the dropdown displays item.orebodyName.  Obviously its projectorebody_id that is read from and entered into the database table, but I want the cell to display orebodyName (as it would with eg MS Access).

Any assistance gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace COL_FIELD by <s>item.orebodyName</s> $select.selected.orebodyName  in the ui-select-match tag.
(If I understand your issue correctly!)

Comment: Thank you. the ui-select-match is outside of the ng-repeat so can't pick up the item.orebodyName..but I think you are on the right track..there must be a COL_? value that I can refer to for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what to do..it was the use of COL_FIELD that confused me... I substituted the standard $select.selected.[fieldname] (ie {{$select.selected.orebodyName}} in my case) and it works fine.